# Extra +4px in CSS calculations w/ FireFox

Tags: html, css, firefox

There are alot of 1px - 4px errors in my display that I've been fixing by resetting the CSS manually (i.e. setting defaults to 0 to normalize between browsers ).

My guess is that I have an un-normalized parameter some where or perhaps I don't understand the box model perfectly.

**Calculations**

Size of Name Box(#hold_name) - 10px (padding top and bottom) + 10px (font size) = 20px.

Size of Image(#hold_picture) - 20px ( defined as height parameter )

Menu Bar(#Aa) - 40px (defined as height parameter )

These are the dimensions I want but the box hangs down too low...

Where is this extra length coming from?

I normalize the p, div, and body tag manually in the fiddle, which I thought would give me a base of 0 for doing my calculations.

I am working in Fire Fox

Comment: Fixed Fiddle  - http://jsfiddle.net/KuYuh/9/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the value for padding in your fiddle and that lined up the box with the image.

```css
#hold_name {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
    color: #FFFFFF;
    display: inline;
    float: right;
    font-size: 10px;
    **padding: 2px;**
    position: relative;
    top: 20px;
}
```

I assume then that you want the box and the image moved up 4 pixels?  Why are you using a

tag for this? I usually use divs and align them with CSS or use divs with tables and align with CSS for that as well.

Comment: It was my line-height setting, it was in the body tag ...but needed to be in the p tag....this accomplished a "reset"...not too sure why it did not inherit this from the body...but it works....gives me a true font-size...instead of adjusted to the what the browser gives it.